# Undefined index uid calling GET fetch

Tags: php, html, sql, fetch

I have a function that calls a SQL query, the function is type fetch_user

Now i get an Undefined Index error when I call my query, The error message is

> Undefined index: uid in profile.php on line 3

But the thing is that i cant find the error,

This is my user.inc.php that have the function

```
function fetch_user_info($uid){
    $uid = (int)$uid;

    $sql = "SELECT
    `user_name` AS `username`,
    `user_email` AS `email`
    FROM `users`
    WHERE `user_id` = {$uid} ";

    $result = mysql_query($sql);

    return mysql_fetch_assoc($result);

}

?>
```

And this is my profile.php that gets the function

```
$user_info = fetch_user_info($_GET['uid']);
print_r($user_info);
```

Any ideas what could be the problem ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It means the GET variable `uid` is unset, so you're doing something wrong when calling the page.
Have you tried going to profile.php?uid=000 (where 000 is a `uid`)

Comment: Yes, I wont get any errors when i go to page profile.php?uid=1 for example.

But i get the error in profile.php

Comment: Well you are right, I was thinking that the error message in profile.php was a "real" error.
But i see now that I works perfect with the uid= ..

Thanks :)

Answer (score 2):

Are you sure that there is uid parameter in GET request?

I mean is there smth like this in url?

http://example.com/profile.php?uid=1

Maybe it is better to check if $_GET['uid'] is isset, by using isset($_GET['uid'])?

I'd try smth like this:

```
$uid = isset($_GET['uid']) ? (int)$_GET['uid'] : 0;
```

and then tried to call the function.

Answer (score 0):

Well, I have faced such error today after doing some updates in my script, the issue hasn't occurred because of the .htaccess file, I missed this:

`Options -MultiViews`

So, now the issue as been resolved.
THank you.